# PHP MVC Sandboxing

Tags: php, model-view-controller, file-permissions, sandbox, chmod

I'm building a system where different users can upload their custom php modules. The system is based on a custom MVC framework written in PHP and deployed on Linux. 
When a user logges in, his modules will be loaded by the system core. The system core is shared between all modules.

My problem is, how to restrict USER modules from messing with the core. Eg. unlinking files, and similar. Can I prevent them from doing that with file permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, each user of your system will have a different user account on your server. If they don't, it will be terribly hard to keep them from deleting each others data.

I'll assume you're working on some flavour of unix server.

- Create one user who owns the MVC system core. This is the admin user. I'll call this user `mvc-admin`.
- Create a group which will allow access to the system core. I'll call this group `g-mvc-access` in this answer.
- do `chown -R mvc-admin:g-mvc-access /path/to/mvc-system-root`. Now the files are all owned by the admin user, and in the access group
- do `chmod -R g+r-w /path/to/mvc-system-root`. Now the group can read, but not write, all the files under the MVC system root.
- Add all your users accounts to the group `g-mvc-access`.

Answer (score 4):

Heaving users upload scripts and execute these is extremely dangerous. Even if you secure your system using `disable_function`, [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) and friends, you might open large security holes.

Instead of letting users upload PHP scripts, I'd suggest that you allow them to upload templates, which consist of a dedicated template language. Such languages typically don't have access to functionality like unlinking files at all. Then you can open up the template language by white-listing, which is a much more secure approach.

The [Zeta Componets Template engine](http://zetac.org/Template) is very extensible and templates are intuitive to write for PHP developers. Maybe this is an option for you?

Comment: Since users will upload a full MVC module, I've already solved the permissions in the View by using Smarty template engine. But my problem is how to secure the controller and model.

Comment: Security wise its a good solution but the code need to be too much intelligent to cater the limitations resulted by restricting the script execution.

Comment: I'm sorry, but IMHO it is (close to) **impossible** to secure uploaded PHP code. :(

Answer (score -1):

you can upload the scripts to a second server which runs a "secured" php.

Then just disable dangerous functions by the **disable_functions** directive:

http://www.webhostgear.com/319.html

Comment: The thing is that system core loads the modules and executes them. So putting the scripts to another server is not an option, since they need to be included in the core.

Comment: Didn't know that limitation. What about an easy (an far from perfect) method: use search&replace before storing the php files?